# moved wordpress to subdirectory-links not working

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-301

I moved a wordpress blog from the root of the site to the /blog directory.

now links like this: domain.com/link-to-post don't redirect to this domain.com/blog/link-to-post

the problem is that I want to put an entirely different app in the root now so I can't do a 301 redirect in there to the /blog folder. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem probably lies in the old links being stored in your WordPress database. You will need to change them to point to the new URL. There's a few ways to do this.

The second part of this link tells you step by step how to do it.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Comment: actually I'm referring to the links in google (on the web) not the one's in the wp-posts table

Comment: Ah. Ok. If all of your posts had categories you may be able to do a redirect on anything with domain.com/category/ to domain.com/category/link-to-post. If there isn't a category then I'm not sure what to do.